# How to use parent radio form control in form array reactive forms angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a `formControl` (Radio) in parent `formGroup` and wanted to use it within `formArray`. Usecase is MCQ Question is having multiple options (`formArray`), wanted to have Radio button with each option to choose correct answer (Only One)

JS

```
private createForm() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
        question: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        correctOption: new FormControl(false),
        options: new FormArray([this.newOption(), this.newOption()])
    });
}

private newOption(): FormGroup {
    const validators = [Validators.required];
    return new FormGroup({
        value: new FormControl('', validators),
        explanation: new FormControl('')
    });
}
```

HTML

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
    <div formArrayName="options">
        <div *ngFor="let option of form.get('options')['controls']; let idx = index">
            <div class="form-group" [formGroupName]="idx">
                <div class="input-group" style="align-items: center">
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="text" placeholder="" formControlName="value" autosize
                        id="option_{{idx}}"></textarea>
                    <span class="input-group-append">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" (click)="removeOption(idx)" tabindex="-1"><i
                                class="fas fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    </span>
                    <span class="input-group-append ml-2 fas">
                        <input id="answer_option_{{idx}}" name="correctOption" type="radio" value="{{idx}}"
                            formControlName="<How to use parent form control correctOption?>" />
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <ckeditor [editor]="editor" formControlName="explanation"
                        [config]="{ placeholder: 'Enter explanation' }">
                    </ckeditor>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you create a StackBlitz?

Comment: @AndreiGătej
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bimunj

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure now what you're trying to achieve. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: If you see the stackblitz, I want to select the correct answer option from 2 options, so I have used Radio Button, the problem is form control of Radio Button is at root level in form, and options are formarray, so inside formarray, how can we use root level formcontrolname?

if there is another way to do it let me know.

Comment: Why do you need to use `root level formcontrolname` ?

Comment: because answer should be only one per question, so I cannot take it with answer options, it has to be along ith question on root level.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to understand the difference between formControlName and [formControl].

**formControlName** is used within your formArrayName / [formGroupName] *(options/idx)* to point out a specific control for each item in your options array.

**[formControl]** is used to point out a specific control in your [formGroup].

To use the a control from the parent, you replace formControlName="correctOption" with [formControl]="correctOption".